# What steps put my bash prompt commands into vim and then back again to bash to execute?

Tags: bash, vim

I've enabled VIM style editing of bash commands at the bash prompt as default bash setting. On a few occasions I've accidentally opened a blank vim file with some complex bash command I was writing.

Awesome. How do I get the newly written line in vim back into bash? I found another post where the author had the [opposite trouble](https://superuser.com/questions/196055/howto-replace-vim-session-screen-buffer-with-previous-bash-activity)--or so it seems.

What steps put my bash prompt commands into vim and then back again to bash to execute?

Comment: In vim, I like to use `:x` to save and exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in normal mode (e.g, when `h` and `l` move the cursor left and right), type `v` to edit the line in `vi`, or in the editor specified by $VISUAL or $EDITOR. When you're done, just save the buffer as you would after editing any other file, using `ZZ` or `:wq` as you prefer.

Comment: I've tried all your suggestions and marked this version because it worked for me. (^x or ^e didn't do anything...) I would add, upon saving the buffer I'm returned to bash and the command was immediately executed. Adding a hash before the command prevented immediate execution of the command.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> will insert your bash command into vim.

To exit vim:

If you are editing (`--INSERT--` or `--REPLACE--` appears at the bottom), press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Then press:

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to save and exit.

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>!</kbd> to quit without saving.

Answer (score 0):

I believe <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> is what you want. Writing the file as normal should execute it i think. So `:wq` in vim.