# linux bash settings for vim

Tags: linux, bash, vim

When I close vim in linux shell bash, part of it viewing is still seen, usually root, but in some other users, usually other than root, vim closed means no viewing document is seen. Where/how can I manage/set this?

Thank you

Comment: Interesting. Which one's the distribution?

Comment: Does this happen when you run vim in a virtual console?

Comment: It sounds like your `$TERM` variable is set wrong.

Comment: I use CentOS release 6.3. I see parts of the file that was opened/viewed when :q was executed. TERM was set to linux. Changed to TERM=xterm and it works fine :)  thank you very much FDinoff (but it does change my colorscheme to default, before was evening, I do not know why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick googling brings a solution: add to your `~/.vimrc` 
`au VimLeave * :!clear`

but the problem seem to be more comlicated:

[How to replace vim screen buffer with previous bash activity after quitting?](https://superuser.com/questions/196055/how-to-replace-vim-screen-buffer-with-previous-bash-activity-after-quitting)

Comment: now it clears the terminal so there is no content, but I would like to be the previous line the line that I start vim, now it is blank screen. It is a CentOS release 6.3 , I also use 6.5, that works fine. Thank you very much